# UICollectionView - Select first cell as View Will Appear

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift2

In my collection view I need to select the first cell as soon as the view appear.

I have implemented `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` When the cell is selected it shows a green border when is not selected the cell has a white border.

What I need to have is to start my app with the first cell with a green border.

I have tried to use `selectItemAtIndexPath` however, the first cell is not showing the green border. What am I missing?

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let firstIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)

        frameCollectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(firstIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)

    }

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let frameCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FrameViewCell

        frameCell.layer.borderWidth = 2
        frameCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let frameCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! FrameViewCell

        frameCell.layer.borderWidth = 1
        frameCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    }
```

Comment: At that point the cells are not loaded yet so you cannot select one.

Comment: I have also tried to add a delay of 5 seconds before the selection is called. But the cell is still not selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. In `viewDidLoad()`:

```
utilityClass.delay(0.1) {
            let indexPathForFirstRow = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.frameCollectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPathForFirstRow, animated: false, scrollPosition: .None)
            self.collectionView(self.frameCollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: indexPathForFirstRow)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The delegate method are not called when you are selecting/deselecting programatically. They are called only if the user selects/deselects.

A better way is to change UI inside the cell class, see for example [Trying to override "selected" in UICollectionViewCell Swift for custom selection state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31329972/trying-to-override-selected-in-uicollectionviewcell-swift-for-custom-selection)

Comment: thank you! I have already looked at that answer however, it will select the cell only when scrolled and not when the view loads

Comment: @SNos When a cell loads, it is not selected.

Comment: Ok but there is a way to get only the first cell on view load with a green border?

Comment: `self.frameCollectionView.delegate?.collectionView!(self.frameCollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0))` will select the cell however, when select another cell the first one is not deselected